# generation of all the possible binary inputs for a lookup table

Tags: c, binary

I have to generate all the possible inputs for a lookup table in C code. I am sure it has to be done recursively but I can't find any way for that. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks

```
int main()
{
    int i,j,k;
    int M,N;
    int comb;
    FILE *fp;

    printf("Insert M and N values \n");
    scanf("%d", &M);
    scanf("%d", &N);
    comb = (int) pow(2.0,M);

    int A[comb][M];
    int B[comb][N];

    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));
    fp = fopen("lut.txt","w"); 
    fprintf(fp, "INPUTPINS - %d\n", M);
    fprintf(fp, "OUTPUTPINS - %d\n", N);
    for (i=0; i< comb; i++)
    {
        for(j= 0; j<M; j++)
        {
            fprintf(fp,"%d", A[i][j]);
        }
        fprintf(fp, " - ");
        for (k=0; k<N; k++)
        {
            B[i][k] = rand()%2;
            fprintf(fp, "%d", B[i][k]);
        }
        fprintf(fp,"\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

I need to generate the values for my matrix A, which will contain all the possible 2^n inputs, while the output would be random.

Comment: Suggestions would be possible *only if* you share some of your code with us.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need arrays or recursion to find the perms. The perms are every number in the range 0 to 2^M - 1. All you need is a function that outputs in binary. And some error checking on `scanf()` and `fopen()` would be better.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void pbinary(FILE *fp, int val, int bits)
{
    int mask = 1 << (bits-1);
    while (bits-- > 0) {
        fprintf (fp, "%d", (val & mask) != 0);
        mask >>= 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i, M, N, comb;
    FILE *fp;
    printf("Insert M and N values \n");
    scanf("%d", &M);
    scanf("%d", &N);
    comb = 1 << M;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    fp = fopen("lut.txt","w"); 
    fprintf(fp, "INPUTPINS - %d\n", M);
    fprintf(fp, "OUTPUTPINS - %d\n", N);
    for (i=0; i< comb; i++)
    {
        pbinary (fp, i, M);
        fprintf(fp, " - ");
        pbinary (fp, rand(), N);
        fprintf(fp,"\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Program input

```
Insert M and N values
3
4
```

File output

```
INPUTPINS - 3
OUTPUTPINS - 4
000 - 1001
001 - 0101
010 - 0110
011 - 0100
100 - 1001
101 - 0011
110 - 0111
111 - 1111
```